# Reset Vimeo player when finish

Tags: jquery, vimeo

I get error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $f is not defined".

jQuery version 1.12.4

And here my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var iframe = document.getElementById("sidebar-video"),
   player = $f(iframe);

   player.addEvent("ready", function() {        
      player.addEvent('finish', function() {
         player.element.src = player.element.src;
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but I think the $f is refering to [flowplayer](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/scripting.html)? so make sure script is loaded.

If you're using Vimeo iframe / HTML5 the following should work

```
//reset vimeo
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

player.on('ended', function() {
    player.element.src = player.element.src;
});
```

Be sure to add the Vimeo api script. I know this is an old post but may be of use.

Comment: Also, if you have Vimeo Pro you can set to reload player in the settings.